# How to add php code into placeholder?

Tags: php

I have script where i set placeholder:

```
 $mailargs = array(

                'nametxt' => '',

                'emailtxt' => '',

                'nameholder' => 'Your Name',

                'emailholder' => 'Your Email Address',

                'submittxt' => 'GO',

                'jsthanks' => true,

                'thankyou' => 'Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list'

            );
```

Now i need to put this part of code in nameholder:

```
<?php _e('Stay in touch with latest news,events and exhibitions by subscribing to our official newsletter', 'wp-test'); ?>
```

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Bit confused about what you are after. `<?php _e($mailargs['thankyou'], 'wp-test'); ?>`? Also loving the profile pic.

Comment: @chriz im not sure that i understand the question... and thx :)

Comment: Are placeholder and nameholder the same thing?

Comment: Why not just add it to `$mailargs`? `'wp-test' => 'Stay in touch with latest news,events and exhibitions by subscribing to our official newsletter'`

Comment: i need to use <?php _e('') ?> because that is translation

Comment: So like `<?php _e($mailargs['thankyou'], 'wp-test'); ?>`? That is the only outcome I can get from your question, I know you are using `wordpress` but I do not know what you are trying to achieve here. This will pull in the `thankyou` text in the `$mailargs` array.

Comment: I have installed plugin for translation  and when i  put <?php _e("Word that i want to translate" 'wp-test'); ?>  plugin recognize that is translation and when i change language it translate that word...is it clear to you now?

Comment: Nearly there, so what do you want `$mailargs` to do? And you say `Now i need to put this part of code in nameholder:` what part do you wish to put in the `_e()` ? Do you wish to translate everything within that array?

Comment: $mailargs is plugin for subscribing and i want to put _e() in nameholder so that i can  translate what ever is in that nameholder(placeholder) when i change language ...  if u know what i mean

Comment: Sorry if this is not what you meant, but you can directly call the `_e()` function from within the `array` itself? https://pastebin.com/9z1BYJLM

Comment: thats it :) tny .. u can post that as answer so that i can accept it :)

Comment: Sure thing, give me a min, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `_e()` function within the array itself:

```
$mailargs = array(

    'nametxt' => '',

    'emailtxt' => '',

    'nameholder' => _e('Your Name','wp-test'),

    'emailholder' => _e('Your Email Address','wp-test'),

    'submittxt' => _e('GO','wp-test'),

    'jsthanks' => true,

    'thankyou' => _e('Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list','wp-test')
);
```

Which will give you the desired result within the `$mailargs` array.